# Knockout custom binding and slow processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am using *Knockout 3.0* to render table data to webpage.

It loads around 200 rows to the table and I am using a custom binding handler for allowing drag and drop functionality into a table column.

This table is getting data from a tree structure of data( multiple for each binding for traversal)

The problem is that, the page is loading very slow in Internet explorer takes around 15 seconds whereas Firefox and chrome are really fast (approx 3 seconds) when compared to IE.

I  trimmed down the code and found that one of my custom binding (which is the droppable one is causing the trouble).

**How can I improve the rendering speed for this in IE. (6,7,8,9)?**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.droppable = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).droppable({
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ".ui-draggable", //  .selected
            tolerance: "pointer",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var data = ko.dataFor(element);
                // Gets dragged item and manipulates the data
            }
        });
    }
};
```

And is called in a table column like  `<td class="outerDroppable b" data=bind="droppable">`

*Possible option which comes to my mind.*

1. Apply the custom binding after entire table data is loaded?? (but how can I do the same)
2. I also tried using deferred updates plugin

Comment: IE9 is already 3 years old, that partly explains the differences. Do you have users with IE<9? I doubt you will have a lot of users with IE6. What IE version gives 15s? Did you try with IE11?

Comment: Even IE 11 is giving that much difference

Comment: Uh, weird, IE11 often does an honest job.

Comment: Are you sure that the binding is the problem, not jQuery UI? How is performance if you manually create 200 rows and bind the droppable to it?

Comment: @janfoeh I removed all the custom bindings and it was still taking 4 seconds to load the same amount of rows. So the slowness is contributed by knockout binding as well

Comment: And you're testing this in IE11? Which mode, standards, compatibility or quirks? Make sure your page renders in standards mode, IE JS performance can differ greatly when its trying to emulate older versions. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2011/09/13/differences-in-javascript-performance-across-ie9-document-modes.aspx

Comment: @janofeh, our customer reported it in IE7, It came back and I tested it in IE11 without any compatibility settings, but still the problem appeared. May be I should post my entire foreach as well , so that SO can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution given in this thread: [How can I make my jquery draggable / droppable code faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552951/how-can-i-make-my-jquery-draggable-droppable-code-faster)

> The presence of so many drop targets seems to make the performance so
>   slow. If possible, try setting the table as a single drop target and
>   calculate the target table cell based on the position data in the drop
>   event.